# Loop doesn't works on a moving file script

Tags: python

I'm quite new to Python and I don't understand why this code crashes without doing anything. It basically moves a file from one folder to another with a message and a delay, and so on.

```
import shutil
import os
import time
    
source_dir = 'C:/Users/Kip/Desktop/tarace'
target_dir = 'C:/Users/Kip/Desktop/tamere'
    
file_names = os.listdir(source_dir)

while True:
    for file_name in file_names:
    shutil.move(os.path.join(source_dir, file_name), target_dir)
    print("OK")
    time.sleep(2)
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: What's the error? Post full stack trace. Also, You have an indention error. Is this deliberate? If not, fix the example to exactly match your code.

Comment: Did you read the error message? (The line(s) after `for` should be indented by four spaces.) Depending on how you run your script, an error message might, for example, get lost when Windows closes the terminal immediately after your program has crashed.

Comment: I would recommend you add a couple of print statements that output your complete source path and complete target path and see if those are what you expect them to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work, but don't forget it will override same named files, if you don't want this you have to check before moving.

```py
import shutil
import os
import time
    
source_dir = 'C:/Users/Kip/Desktop/tarace'
target_dir = 'C:/Users/Kip/Desktop/tamere'
    
while True:
    file_names = os.listdir(source_dir)
    if(file_names):
        print("files found moving..")
        for file_name in file_names:
            old_path = os.path.join(source_dir, file_name)
            new_path = os.path.join(target_dir, file_name)
            shutil.move(old_path, new_path)
            print("file {0} -> moved to {1}".format(old_path, new_path))
    time.sleep(2)
```

Comment: I think I haven't used the word "crash" properly. Actually, the window just closes itself right after I run the script, without any changes to both folders. So it doesn't "crash", it just doesn't works. Anyway, your script is working, thanks ! However, it works just for one time when there is a file to move. When there isn't any file, the script stops. That's why I added "while True", to continuously watch folder and move any incoming file. That's not the right thing to do ?

Comment: That is right thing to do, but you didn't touch that part. I edited it now it moves continuously.

Comment: Hmm interesting. Well I far away to be able to do that by myself, I think I have to go back to the basics ! Thanks alot.